# Could we travel faster than the speed of light in a medium, but slower than the speed of light in vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, refraction, faster-than-light, cherenkov-radiation

It is well accepted that nothing with mass can travel at the speed of light in vacuum, $c$. Now let's say that a light wave is traveling through a medium that slows the wave's speed significantly (less than $c$). Since we are able to accelerate objects to over 99% the speed of light (via LHC), could we potentially create a situation in which we could view a stationary light wave as Einstein first wondered during his childhood?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1307/50583

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

> Cherenkov radiation, also known as Vavilov–Cherenkov radiation, is
>   electromagnetic radiation emitted when a charged particle (such as an
>   electron) passes through a dielectric medium at a speed greater than
>   the phase velocity of light in that medium. The characteristic blue
>   glow of an underwater nuclear reactor is due to Cherenkov radiation.
>
> [image]
>
> *Source: [Cherenkov radiation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation)*