# Is the speed of light universal for all mediums?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, refraction, faster-than-light, cherenkov-radiation

We know that the speed of light is constant in a vacuum and has the value **c**= 3× 10^8 m/s.
But in a medium such as glass(refractive index=1.5) the speed of light is 2× 10^8 m/s. Now considering the fact that the glass is also a part of the universe, and the maximum speed limit of the universe is **c**, so is it possible to cross the speed of light in a medium such as glass?
Or is it that for any medium, the maximum speed that can be achieved is the speed of light?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if light/particles exceeded the speed of light for a particular medium](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1307/)

Comment: Yeah, i got  it that particles can indeed travel faster than light in some media, giving rise to Cherenkov radiation. But then how is **c** related to the speed of light?

Comment: @VivekPandey: $c$ is speed of light in vacuum.