# Can an object move faster than the speed of light in a medium?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, refraction, faster-than-light, cherenkov-radiation

In water the speed of light changes to $2.25 \cdot 10^8m/s$.   Can a electron travel faster/travel at the same speed   in water. I don't see any violation of SR. So   shouldn't it  be possible for an electron to travel at say $2.5 \cdot 10^8m/s $. Water is just an example.In other mediums like hydrogen electrons in excited states should travel at higher speeds than that of light in the same medium.

Comment: yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1307/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes . But according to Special Relativity , no particle can go past the speed of causality (also known as speed of light in vacuum)($2.998 $ x $ 10^8 $ m/s)in any medium .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can, the limit is 299792458 m/s.

For example  in water the speed of light is reduced by the refraction index, and therefore a particle exceeding (c/n) does not violate the SR.
Read more here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, for instance electrons regularly win the race against photons in water.
And they emit radiation known as [Cherenkov Radiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation). It's properties are similar to those of the shockwaves produced when an object crosses the sound barrier: a classical conical shockwave, just with light in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum speed of light is defined as the velocity of electromagnetic waves in a vacuum. Light is a range of electromagnetic wavelengths that can be detected by our eyes. Electromagnetic waves traveling through a non-vacuum region can be "slowed down" by interactions with matter/energy present in the non-vacuum region. As another commentator stated, other non-electromagnetic-wave mass/energy entities (atoms,sub-atomic particles),can pass through identical regions at a higher velocity than light (electromagnetic waves), Neutrinos are a primary example of matter particles that may achieve this higher velocity in a non-vacuum. No neutrino, or anything else that has rest-mass, can ever attain the velocity of light in vacuum.