# Light travels in a medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, waves, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

According to Snell's law :

$${n_1 \over n_2} = {v_2 \over v_1}$$

$v_2 = v_1 n_1 / n_2$

Assuming that $n_1$ is vacuum , we will find the following equation:

$$v = c / n$$

(We may find the same equation directly according to the definition of refractive index : $v  = c /n$)

Theoretically , according to this equation in a certain medium the speed of light can become small and even 0.

1- Under these conditions , will the light will be at rest ?

2- If true , a viewer in such medium can move faster than the speed of light. Theoretically, is such occasion possible ? Under certain conditions , is it possible to move faster than the light?

Comment: Be aware that in the photon picture the individual photons still move at the vacuum speed of light. It is the *coherent* scattering off the atoms and molecules in the medium that leads to an effectively slower speed of light. Now, this explanation I just gave has a ton of problem of its own which I conveniently evaded by writing '*coherent*'.

Comment: For a nice layman’s discussion of this point, I refer you to [this excellent interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiHN0ZWE5bk) in Brady Haran's Youtube series *Sixty Symbols*. There's also another video which takes on quite a different point of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Light will never be completely at rest, but we have succeeded in slowing it down significantly. (See [this](http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/story?id=99111) for example)

In a medium, particles can move faster than the speed of light. (The speed of light in that medium)
In fact, this is used in some particle accelerators to detect certain particles.
When a charged particle travels faster than the speed of light in a medium, it emits Cherenkov Radiation. (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation) for a brief explanation)

Comment: Another description of slowing the speed of light in a Bose-Einstein condensate: http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/1999/02.18/light.html.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am just looking for little more explanation why light will never be completely at rest. Is there particular reason for that ?

Comment: @Michael Look up this [post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11820/what-really-cause-light-photons-to-appear-slower-in-media), if you want deeper analysis of speed of light in medium.