# Why does a light wave travel at a different speed when the density of medium is different

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, refraction

Why does light waves travel at different speeds when the density of medium changes? Can you slow down light?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the light travel slower in denser medium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105573/)

Comment: no it does not, that post seem's very complicated and there is many negative comand for the answer in that post , not sure if it's answer is right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What really causes light/photons to appear slower in media?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11820/)