Why the photons are deflected during the refraction?
From what I learnt, when photons are passing throw a denser environnement with an positive angle (from the atmosphere to water for exemple), they are slow down. But I can't understand how this slowdown can change the trajectory of the photons, an so create refraction.
Please help me...

You have to use wave propagation and not the picture of a single photon

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11820/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466/2451 and links therein.

What if we just throw one single photon ?

Even a single photon can be seen as wave.

The photon behaviour is described by the wave.

Actually it is phase matching at the interface, giving Snell law. The latter can coincide in certain cases with the quickest path of a particle with those speeds.
